# .htaccess, <Directory />, gives Internal Server Error, 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Where and how to use `<Directory />` in order to prevent files and folder access in the `/` . `<Directory />` gives for me 500 Internal Server error.

.htaccess

```
#if i add the next 6 lines (10 lines), i am getting the error "Internal Server Error"

    <Directory />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Options None
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /web>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options -MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex /web/index.php

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.somedomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/somedomain\.com" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index\.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory: _"Context: server config, virtual host"_ (If you don’t know what that means, click on _Context_ in the linked page)

Comment: thank you, i follow the documentation, but it does not work

Comment: No, if you are trying to put this into .htaccess, you are not following the documentation.

Comment: which line has a mistake? I am getting 500 error only from the <Directive />, Rewrite is working.

Comment: I already quoted the relevant part of the documentation for you.

Comment: Thank you, seems the `<Directory>` is not applicable in `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

Directory location must contain full relative path including /var/www/ or whatever you have there.

Hope it helps!